# embedding previously loaded ajax div content on web page in order to save it or send it by e-mail

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain, call

I managed to successfully load and correctly display, on an ASPX page, some div contents on an external website by using the wonderful "Cross-domain requests with jQuery" script available at James Padolsey's website (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/). 
Now i'm stuck on a big problem: 
if i save locally the resulting web page or send it by e-mail, the previously loaded content just disappears and my  container DIV is empty/blank.
Is there a simple way to "embed" the actual loaded content on my container DIV *as* HTML code so i can display it as normal HTML code? Or any other way that keeps visible the container div's content on my web page after i save it locally or send it by e-mail by using Outlook's "send page by e-mail" tool? 
Here's my code:

```html
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.externalwebsite.any/webpage.asp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
    var $tabLista = $(res.responseText).find('#listaOfferte').html();
        document.getElementById("tabLista").innerHTML = $tabLista;
        }
}); 
</script>

<div id="tabLista"></div>
```

Thank you so much for your help! I'm a total newbie on this kind of scripts and i really need your help! :)

Tiz

Comment: The user can use the browser's `Print` function. This usually has an option to save a PDF.

Comment: Yes, but i don't have to "print" the page, i specifically need to send the resulting page (with the loaded divs) by e-mail with the Outlook tool ("File/Send page by e-mail"). :-)

Comment: As an alternative approach, a "printable" static (HTML) version of the resulting ASPX page would be a great option! ;-)
(such as an immediate redirect from ASPX page to the exact copy HTML page)